# Error:: is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Tags: r

When I am using below code then it gives me the desired output

```
subset(ndata,!is.na(ndata$LHeart_Failure))
```

While when I did the above same code in other form

```
out <- "LHeart_Failure"
subset(ndata,!is.na(ndata$out))
```

it is giving me error:

```
logical(0)
Warning message:
In is.na(ndata$out) :
is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Here ndata is the data from the .csv file. LHeart_Failure is the name of the column, by which I want to find the all the rows in which there is no "NA" in that particular column(i.e all the rows in which there is no NA in LHeart_Failure).

Comment: Please check your column out is existing in your ndata then try your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this error message when I try to call `is.na()` on a data frame column which does not exist, e.g.

```
> ndata <- data.frame(v1=c(1:3), v2=c("one", "two", "three"))
> subset(ndata, !is.na(ndata$out))
[1] v1 v2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
Warning message:
In is.na(ndata$out) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

So you should make sure that the column `out` actually exists first before trying to subset using it.

I would personally avoid using `subset` and instead just subset the data frame explicitly.  From what you wrote, it looks like you want to retain rows from the data frame `ndata` where the `out` column does *not* have an `NA` value.  In this case, you can try:

```
ndata[!is.na(ndata$out), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the data structure `ndata`does not contain any column called `out`. With the command:

```
out <- "LHeart_Failure"
```

you only create a variable `out` with the string content `"LHeart_Failure"`. If you want to use `out` as a equivalent to the `LHeart_Failure` column, you have to call:

```
out <- ndata$LHeart_Failure
```

followed by

```
found_idxs <- which[!is.na(out)]
```

Comment: For clarification I want to add that by "variable `out`" (presumably) not a data set variable is ment, but a programming variable (in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Yes! I prefer the word FIELD for a "variable" of a data set.

Comment: @FlorianSchunke does it works out <- ndata$LHeart_Failure

Comment: @lokesh it creates a null vector with a variable name out

Comment: If `out <- ndata$LHeart_Failure` gives you a null vector, then `subset(ndata,!is.na(ndata$LHeart_Failure))` should not work either. Because `out <- ndata$LHeart_Failure` just asigning the column vector of the column with the name `LHeart_Failure` to a new variable `out`.

Answer (score 0):

`ndata$out` assumes that the column `out` exists in the data `ndata`.
If you want to use the string you've saved in `out` as the column name to filter the data, I suggest you do this:

```
out <- "LHeart_Failure"
ndata[!is.na(ndata[,out]),]
```