# Filter dataframe rows depending on columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe Train_classifier  with this structure :

```
Note.Reco  Reason.Reco  Suggestion.Reco  Contact
9          absent       tomorrow          yes
8          absent                         yes
8          present      today             no
5                       yesterday         no
```

I would like to delete from this dataframe all the rows where the column "Note.Reco" and "Reason.Reco" have an empty value.

The expected result :

```
Note.Reco  Reason.Reco  Suggestion.Reco  Contact
    9          absent       tomorrow          yes
    8          absent                         yes
    8          present      today             no
```

I try with this R code :

```
Train <- Train_classifier[!(!is.na(Train_classifier$Reason.Reco) & Train_classifier$Reason.Reco==''), ]
```

I get this error messsage :

```
Warning message:
In is.na(Train_classifier$Reason.Reco) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

And an empty result dataframe

Any idea pleasE?

Thank you

Comment: You sure that the empty cell in Reason.Reco is NA? In your example, it rather looks like it's an empty string.

Comment: Please update your question with `dput(Train_classifier)` . Can be an issue with the `class` of `Reason.Reco` column. Also you might want to check your condition to filter once again.

Comment: `is.na(NULL)` reproduces your error. My guess is that column Reason.Reco  does not exist. Maybe there is a whitespace in the column name.

Comment: Quite a possibility @LyzandeR . You can also check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718462/error-is-na-applied-to-non-list-or-vector-of-type-null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Train_classifier[Train_classifier$Note.Reco!="" & Train_classifier$Reason.Reco!="",]
```